# URL links for collapsed comments that are not upvoted do not work because they are not displayed in the browser window

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

When trying to link a comment using the ID #hashtag via inspect element, it doesn't link because the comment is collapsed. Only upvoted comments can be linked.

For example:

Collapsed comment [#comment-36497903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36497903)

Uncollapsed comment [#comment-36498421](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36498421)

[Why does Node.js' Assert.js use !!!value in their code? What purpose does it serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36497903)

Comment: Clicking on the time that the comment was posted (e.g. 1 hour ago, 16 mins ago etc) will show the link you can use. E.g. [uncollapsed comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36496457_23741106), [collapsed comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36498545_23741106).

Comment: Oh well, just thought that I could link to an id.

Comment: Oh, this new generation ! ;-) This is not a "#hashtag", this is an #anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Each comment has a timestamp next to it that is also a permanent URL; use *that* link instead. The comment will be loaded with the page as needed.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36498545_23741106
```

works [just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment36498545_23741106).

You can shorten a comment url by using *just* the comment id with:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/<commentid>
```

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/36498545